# Automating Spotify using Python and Youtube API - Error 403: The request is missing a valid API key

Tags: python, google-api, youtube-data-api, spotify, passport-google-oauth

I am working on a project here which grabs my YouTube account playlist and then adds each song to my Spotify likes. This is my first project with Python and API's so I may sound confused here.

I am using my google OAUTH Client 2.0 to authenticate once I run the program. I enter in the new key that they give me after authenticating and then select which playlist I want to grab songs from.

Then my issue occurs once I select the playlist I want to use. The execution then stops and gives me this error after a request.execute() call:

```
"googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 404 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?playlistId=%3Cyoutube_client.Playlist+object+at+0x0000028A3C883948%3E&part=id%2C+snippet&maxResults=50&alt=json returned "The playlist identified with the request's <code>playlistId</code> parameter cannot be found.">
```

When I click the link this message appears:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 403,
    "message": "The request is missing a valid API key.",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "The request is missing a valid API key.",
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "forbidden"
      }
    ],
    "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED"
  }
}
```

Here is the code that the execution stops:

```
def get_videos_from_playlist(self, playlist_id):
        songs = []
        request = self.youtube_client.playlistItems().list(
            playlistId=playlist_id,
            part="id, snippet",
            maxResults=50
        )
        response = request.execute()
```

I'm confused where its asking me for my missing API but I am using the Google OAUTH 2.0 Client to authenticate. I thought I didn't need one if I have the other. Do I need both? Do I need to add something to the client secrets?

EDIT

Here is what the call looks like in my run.py:

```
def run():
    #1. Get a list of our playlists from Youtube
    
    youtube_client = YouTubeClient('./creds/secrets.json')
    spotify_client = SpotifyClient(os.getenv('SPOTIFY_AUTH_TOKEN'))
    playlists = youtube_client.get_playlists()

    #2. Ask which playlist we want to get the music videos from
    
    for index, playlist in enumerate(playlists):
        print(f"{index}: {playlist.title}")
    choice = int(input("Enter your choice: "))
    chosen_playlist = playlists[choice]
    print(f"You selected: {chosen_playlist.title}")
    
    #3 For each video in the playlist, get the song information from Youtube
    songs = youtube_client.get_videos_from_playlist(chosen_playlist)
    print(f"Attempting to add {len(songs)}")
```

Here is the my youtube_client.py:

```
def __init__(self, credentials_location):
        # youtube_dl default User-Agent can cause some json values to return as None, using Facebook's web crawler solves this.
        youtube_dl.utils.std_headers['User-Agent'] = "facebookexternalhit/1.1 (+http://www.facebook.com/externalhit_uatext.php)"
        
        scopes = ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.readonly"]

        # Disable OAuthlib's HTTPS verification when running locally.
        # *DO NOT* leave this option enabled in production.
        os.environ["OAUTHLIB_INSECURE_TRANSPORT"] = "1"

        api_service_name = "youtube"
        api_version = "v3"

        # Get credentials and create an API client
        flow = google_auth_oauthlib.flow.InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
            credentials_location, scopes)
        credentials = flow.run_console()
        youtube_client = googleapiclient.discovery.build(
            api_service_name, api_version, credentials=credentials)

        self.youtube_client = youtube_client

    def get_playlists(self):
        request = self.youtube_client.playlists().list(
            part="id, snippet",
            maxResults=50,
            mine=True
        )
        response = request.execute()

        playlists = [Playlist(item['id'], item['snippet']['title']) for item in response['items']]

        return playlists
```

Comment: Your `<youtube_client.Playlist object at 0x0000028A3C883948>` is not a YouTube playlist ID! Please show some context around the caller of `get_videos_from_playlist`. And the code that initiates the OAuth flow (editing out credentials data, of course).

Comment: Hi @stvar, thanks for your help. I just edited the question with regards to your comments. Im confused here seeing as the code is able to go in and see the playlist I have and actually display their names but not able to get the ID. Maybe im gathering the wrong one.

Answer (score 0):

The parameter `playlist_id` of function `get_videos_from_playlist` should be a playlist's ID (since it is passed on to the parameter [`playlistId`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems/list#playlistId) of the [`PlaylistItems.list`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems/list) API endpoint).

But, by the code:

```
songs = youtube_client.get_videos_from_playlist(
    chosen_playlist)
```

the actual type of `playlist_id` is the class `Playlist` (which your code above does not show).

You must fix your call to `get_videos_from_playlist` above by passing to it the ID that is retained by the `chosen_playlist` instance of `Playlist` class.

In case your `Playlist` class is something like:

```
class Playlist:

    def __init__(self, id, title):
        self.id = id
        self.title = title
```

then your fixed code would look as:

```
songs = youtube_client.get_videos_from_playlist(
    chosen_playlist.id)
```

Comment: By any chance, is your project related to [this one on Github](https://github.com/enkay-28/Spotify-Youtube-Playlist-Automation)?

Comment: It worked! Thank you for your help. I appreciate it. :)